# Disable Google maps for few pagelayouts/objects

Tags: google-map

Right now you can enable or disable the google maps feature by going to

Customize > Maps and Locations > Settings -> Enable Maps and Location Services

This will either enable or disable for all objects.

I don't see an option to disable for some objects/page layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an idea for this and here is the [link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjR2AAK)

Comment: Can you rephrase this question and answer so they actually are a question and an answer?